# Validate JSON against JSON schema (in Java)

Tags: java, json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am using ***com.github.fge.jsonschema***. Working in Java.

Following is the JSON Schema.

```
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Employee",
    "description": "employee description",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "eid": {
            "description": "The unique identifier for a emp",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "ename": {
            "description": "Name of the emp",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "qual":{
            "$ref": "#/definitions/qualification"   
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "qualification": 
        {
            "description": "Qualification",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the JSON to validate against schema.

```
{
    "eid":1000,
    "ename": "mrun",
    "qualification": "BE"
}
```

The issue is that it is validating type (i.e. integer or string) properly for eid and ename, if we pass any wrong data.
For eg:

```
{
    "eid":"Mrun", //should be Integer
    "ename": 72831287, //should be String
    "qualification": 98372489 //should be String
}
```

If we pass wrong type for qualification only then it validating as true (i.e. it does not validate the type for qualification maybe because it is nested).

Need to perform the validations for the whole JSON.

***Is there any other solution to validate nested objects in JSON?***

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Is this your whole schema? Does it validate the whole thing as correct? It looks like the only possible issue is as per the first answer posted... you have `properties>qual` rather than `properties>qualification`. Otherwise it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your example

```
{
    "eid":"Mrun",
    "ename": 72831287,
    "qualification": 98372489
}
```

does not match your schema. Your schema expects objects like

```
{
    "eid": "Mrun",
    "ename": 72831287,
    "qual": {
        "qualification": 98372489
    }
}
```

But if you just want to reuse the "qualification" definition, your schema should look similar to

```
"properties": {
    "eid": {
        "description": "The unique identifier for a emp",
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "ename": {
        "description": "Name of the emp",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "qualification":{
        "$ref": "#/definitions/qualification"   
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an invalid schema. `allOf` only has meaning when used in a schema or subschema object as it applies the subschemas.

Comment: I have checked my schema online JSON schema validator, the schema is right. My concern is  that the qualification is a string but when I am passing integer it is still validating it as true, which is wrong.

Comment: No, your schema is not correct. Just paste it into https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ and validate it against your example, then paste my schema and validate against your example and see that my schema is correct because it marks qualification as needed to be string.